# Not getting expected output when calculating percentage in SQL using Count

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm running a query but it doesn't output what I expect it to. I have the table below:

```
------------------------
security_ID | Date | Rep 
------------------------
2256        |202001|  0
2257        |202002|  0
2257        |202003|  0
2256        |202002|  1
2256        |202003|  2
2257        |202003|  1
```

I'm essentially trying to find the % of cases where the column `Rep` changes from 0 to 1, from one date to the next, when `Rep` was 0 for the previous date, for a given `security_ID`.  The difference in the `Date`s  should be 1 (for eg. with 202002-202001 = 1. Dates are integer here) for the calculation.
Here, for the `security_ID = 2256`, the `Percent = 100` as from `202001` to `202002`, `Rep` changes from 0 to 1, and in the table the number of rows where `2256` was `0` is 1. The equation for Percent is:

Percent = (No of cases where Rep_current = 1 and Rep_prev = 0)/(No of cases where Rep_prev = 0) * 100

For security_ID = 2257, Percent = 1/2 * 100 = 50

For example, I want the output to be:

```
----------------------------------
security_ID | Date | Rep | Percent
----------------------------------
2256        |202001|  0  |  100
2257        |202002|  0  |  50 
2257        |202003|  0  |  50 
2256        |202002|  1  |  100 
2256        |202003|  2  |  100
2257        |202003|  1  |  50
```

I tried to do this as follows:

```
SELECT security_ID, Date, Rep, 
(COUNT(CASE WHEN Rep_prev = 0 and Rep = 1 then 1 else 0 end)/count(CASE WHEN Rep_prev = 0 then 1 else 0 end) * 100) as "Percent"
from
(
    select t1.security_id,t1.date,t1.rep,
           coalesce(t2.rep,0) as Rep_prev
      from mytable t1
      left join mytable t2
        on t1.security_id = t2.security_id
       and t2.date = t1.date - 1
    )
GROUP BY SECURITY_ID, Date, Rep
```

But I get the output as:

```
----------------------------------
security_ID | Date | Rep | Percent
----------------------------------
2256        |202001|  0  |  100
2257        |202002|  0  |  100 
2257        |202003|  0  |  100 
2256        |202002|  1  |  100 
2256        |202003|  2  |  100
2257        |202003|  1  |  100
```

Not too sure where my logic is off here.

Please let me know if youd like more info, cause its hard to put this idea across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below logic (using Windows function) -

```
Select mt.security_id, mt.Date, mt.Rep, (numerator*100)/denominator As "Percent"
from
  (Select security_id,
       SUM(case when Rep_curr = 1 and coalesce(Rep_prev,-99) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) As numerator,
       SUM(case when coalesce(Rep_prev,-99) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) As denominator
    from
     (Select security_id, 
             Rep As Rep_curr,
             lag(Rep,1) over(partition by security_id order by Date) As Rep_prev
      from my_table) t 
   where t.Rep_prev is not NULL
   group by security_id) tab
   join my_table mt 
   on tab.security_id = mt.security_id;
```

Here is a db fiddle link that demonstrates how it works in SQL Server - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8654f0242bbed911f1ed63b795281bac. The above syntax would work on Sybase as well.

**EDIT :**
If I were to use your methodology, here is how I would do it -

```
SELECT mt.*, Tab1.Perct As "Percent"
FROM
    (SELECT security_ID,
            (SUM(CASE WHEN Rep_prev = 0 and Rep = 1 then 1 else 0 end) * 100/SUM(CASE WHEN Rep_prev = 0 then 1 else 0 end)) as Perct
    from
       (
        select t1.security_id,t1.date,t1.rep,
               coalesce(t2.rep,0) as Rep_prev
          from mytable t1
          left join mytable t2
            on t1.security_id = t2.security_id
           and t2.date = t1.date - 1
          where  t2.rep IS NOT NULL
        ) t
    GROUP BY SECURITY_ID ) Tab1
    JOIN mytable mt
    ON TAB1.security_ID = mt.security_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks. Im just trying to understand the 2nd query. I dont understand why `(SUM(CASE WHEN Rep_prev = 0 and Rep = 1 then 1 else 0 end) * 100/SUM(CASE WHEN Rep_prev = 0 then 1 else 0 end)) as Perct` cant just be in the outermost `SELECT` statement. I guess I just dont understand why there is the first sub-query, since the second sub-query is the only sub-query I was trying to use. Thanks

Comment: The percentage field post computation has full functional dependency only on security_id and not the other fields. In other words, when we are comparing the prev or current value we are doing that for different records of a specific security Id value which represents 3 records in this case however if we group by all the fields, a specific combination of all the fields represent on a single record so there is no before or after to compare against. So, it needs to computed at the granularity of security_id and not security_id, date & rep & then we can get other detailed fields using security_id.

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment was too long so this is the 2nd part. In your approach, count will always give you 100% since count treats both 1 and 0 as the same so for each row it will compute numerator and denominator as 1. That’s why, you should use sum - when you do in your approach you would get divide by zero error because it’s doing the computation for each row as you have specified all the fields in group by (specific combination of all fields always represent a single record here).

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helps me understand.

Comment: Can you please upvote /accept my answer if it worked for you. Thank you!!

Comment: The calculation is slightly off though. For example for `Security_id = 2345`, the rows are `[FDATE | Rep] = [202003 | 0], [20204|0], [20205|0], [20206|0],  [20207|1]`, but the `Perct` is 20 when it should be 1/4 = 25

Comment: I am getting 25% using both my methods above. Please check out the DB fiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c5280c2c0931102129406f193ca768a6. It should work fine if you use my queries above unless you change something or make any updates on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Using window functions, this looks like:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(case when prev_rep = 0 and rep = 1 then 100.0 else 0 end) over (partition by security_id) /
        sum(case when rep = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by security_id)
       ) as precent
from (select t.*,
             lag(rep) over (partition by security_id order by date) as prev_rep
      from mytable t
     ) t;
```

If you are using a version of Sybase that doesn't support window functions, then you can calculate this *per security_id* using:

```
select security_id,
       (sum(case when prev_rep = 0 and rep = 1 then 100.0 else 0 end) /
        sum(case when rep = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as precent
from (select t.*,
             (select top (1) t2.rep
              from mytable t2
              where t2.security_id = t.security_id and
                    t2.date < t.date
              order by t2.date desc
             ) as prev_rep
      from mytable t
     ) t
group by security_id;
```

You can then `join` this back to your table if you need this per row.

EDIT:

If you have rows for every month, then perhaps this will work:

```
select security_id,
       (sum(case when prev_rep = 0 and rep = 1 then 100.0 else 0 end) /
        sum(case when rep = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as precent
from (select t.*, tprev.rep as prev_rep
      from mytable t left join
           mytable tprev
           on t.security_id = tprev.security_id and
              convert(date, tprev.date + '01') = dateadd(month, -1, convert(date, t.date + '01'))
     ) t
group by security_id;
```

Note:  This assumes that `date` is a string.  Storing it as a proper `date` would simplify the logic.

Comment: The Sybase version I use doesn't support `LAG` so I tried the 2nd query but this gives an error `Sybase Database Error: Feature, Scalar value subquery (at line 6) inside a conditional expression is not supported.`. I looked up the error but am  not clear how to resolve it

Comment: @Jojo . . . That is weird.  Does the subquery run by itself?  The subquery is not inside a conditional expression, so the error is quite strange.

Comment: @GodronLinoff I tried running the subquery alone and it gives the error: `Feature, TOP/FIRST/LIMIT in a subquery, is not supported`

Comment: @Jojo . . . You might consider upgrading to a more functional database.

Comment: Its company specified sadly so there isn't much I can do about hat